# Timer is running infinately and I cant tell why

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

So I have this module that handles voting and the timer. When a vote comes in AND its valid AND voting threshold is met. it starts the timer. Now this resulted in an infinate loop where when a timer finished it created a new timer and ran it. If this was happening I would have assumed Id see miltiple timers running side by side but instead I assume they were stacked.

1. Why exactly is the timer running again after its done. Look at log file to see handle msg was not called again after voting.
2. What should I do to get this proper. I'm new to coding and this is my biggest project. feel free to let me know im making mistakes :D

```
const { r } = require('./redisClient');
const axios = require('axios');


let userVotes = {};

let viewerCount = 0;
let votingThreshold = viewerCount/2;
const handleMessage = async (channel, tags, message, self) => {
    //if msg is greater than 1 character, ignore.


    const vote = parseInt(message, 10);
    
    if (vote >= 1 && vote <= 32) {
        console.log(`${tags.username} voted for ${vote}`);
        // Calculate grid position based on the vote.
        const rowIndex = Math.floor((vote - 1) / 8);
        const colIndex = (vote - 1) % 8;

        // Check if the vote is valid by checking its Redis value.
        let grid = await r.get('Grid'+(rowIndex)); // Assuming you're storing data in Redis in this string format.
        
        grid = JSON.parse(grid);
        const gridValue = grid[colIndex][2];
        console.log(gridValue);
        if (gridValue === 2|| gridValue === 3 && grid[colIndex][3] !== 'True') {
            
            //if the user has already voted, remove their previous vote from the grid
            if (tags.username in userVotes) {
                const previousVote = userVotes[tags.username];
                const previousRowIndex = Math.floor((previousVote - 1) / 8);
                const previousColIndex = (previousVote - 1) % 8;
                grid[previousColIndex][0] -= 1;
            }
            //add user's vote to userVotes
            userVotes[tags.username] = vote;
            console.log('vote valid');
            //increase grid vote by 1
            grid[colIndex][0] += 1;
            r.set(`Grid`+(rowIndex), JSON.stringify(grid));
            //if user has already voted, remove their previous vote
            if (Object.keys(userVotes).length >=votingThreshold) {
                startTimer();
            }
            console.log(Object.keys(userVotes).length)
            r.set(`VoteCount`, JSON.stringify(Object.keys(userVotes).length));

        }
        else {
            console.log('not a valid vote.');
        }
    }
};

resetUserVotes = () =>
    userVotes = {}

resetGridVotes = async () => {
    //if a grid item is 2 or 3, set its [0] to 0
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        console.log('Grid'+i);
        let grid = await r.get('Grid'+i); // Assuming you're storing data in Redis in this string format.
        grid = JSON.parse(grid);
        for (let j = 0; j < grid.length; j++){
            if (grid[j][2] === 2 || grid[j][2] === 3){
                grid[j][0] = 0;
                grid[j][2] = 2;
            }
        }
        r.set('Grid'+i, JSON.stringify(grid));
    }
    
    console.log('Grid votes have been reset.');
};


getTopVoted = () => {
    if (Object.keys(userVotes).length === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    const votes = Object.values(userVotes);
    const topVote = votes.reduce((a, b) => {
        return votes.filter(vote => vote === a).length >= votes.filter(vote => vote === b).length ? a : b;
    }, null);
    return topVote;
};

let topVoted = null;

updateTopVoted = async () => {
    console.log(isVotingActive);
    currentVote = getTopVoted();
    if (isVotingActive === false){
        return
    }
    if (currentVote === null) {
        console.log('No votes yet.');
        setTimeout(updateTopVoted, 1000);
        return;
    }
    if (topVoted !== currentVote) {
        //set grid top voted to 2 and grid current vote to 3
        const rowIndex = Math.floor((currentVote - 1) / 8);
        const colIndex = (currentVote - 1) % 8;
        let grid = await r.get(`Grid`+rowIndex); // Assuming you're storing data in Redis in this string format.
        grid = JSON.parse(grid);
        grid[colIndex][2] = 3;

        if (topVoted !== null) {
            const rowIndex = Math.floor((topVoted - 1) / 8);
            const colIndex = (topVoted - 1) % 8;
            grid[colIndex][2] = 2;
        }
        topVoted = currentVote;
        r.set(`Grid`+rowIndex, JSON.stringify(grid));
        console.log(`Top voted is now ${topVoted}`);
        setTimeout(updateTopVoted, 1000);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(updateTopVoted, 1000);
        console.log(`Top voted is still ${topVoted}`);
    }
};
let timer = 20;
const timerDefault = 20;
const startTimer = () => {
    
    if (timer > 0) {
        console.log(timer);
        timer--;
        r.set(`Timer`, JSON.stringify(timer));
        console.log('Timer running...' + timer);
        setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
        
    } else {
        console.log('Timer finished!');
        stopVoting();
        pauseEvents();
        openCase();
        timer = timerDefault;
    }
};

const openCase = () => {
    //16 will be col 8 row 1
    //17 will be col 0 row 2
    //18 will be col 1 row 2
    //19 will be col 2 row 2
    //24 will be col 0 row 3

    colIndex = (topVoted - 1) % 8;
    rowIndex = Math.floor((topVoted - 1) / 8);
    const c = colIndex;
    const r = rowIndex;
    
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/openCase?topVoted=${topVoted}&c=${c}&r=${r}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            startVoting();
        }
    );
};



const startVoting = () => {
    isVotingActive = true;
    client.on('message', handleMessage); // Attach the event listener
    console.log('Voting has started!');
    resetGridVotes();
    updateTopVoted();
    resetUserVotes();
    resumeEvents();
};

const stopVoting = () => {
    isVotingActive = false;
    client.removeListener('message', handleMessage); // Remove the event listener
    console.log('Voting has stopped!');
};

const updateViewers = async (newViewers) => {
    viewerCount = parseInt(newViewers);
    votingThreshold = Math.floor(viewerCount / 2);
    console.log(viewerCount)
    console.log(`Viewers has been set to ${newViewers}`);
    r.set(`LiveViewerCount`, JSON.stringify(viewerCount));
    
};

const pauseEvents= (req,res) => {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:1234/DoAction',
        data: {
            "action": {
                "id": "2a094d23-55aa-46cc-ad98-01bf5224f9ad",
                "name": "pause"
            },
    }
    })
};
const resumeEvents = (req,res) => {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:1234/DoAction',
        data: {
            "action": {
                "id": "56935fa0-3325-4f3a-8c02-e9005f246a96",
                "name": "resume"
            },
    }
    })
}
  


// more voting-related functions

module.exports = {
    handleMessage,
    resetUserVotes,
    resetGridVotes,
    startTimer,
    startVoting,
    stopVoting,
    updateTopVoted,
    openCase,
    timer,
    updateViewers

};
```

LOG COPY

```
No votes yet.
true
No votes yet.
true
No votes yet.
zekimar voted for 1
2
vote valid
20
Timer running...19
1
true
Top voted is now 1
19
Timer running...18
true
Top voted is still 1
18
Timer running...17
true
Top voted is still 1
17
Timer running...16
true
Top voted is still 1
5
5
Viewers has been set to 5
Viewers has been set to 5
16
Timer running...15
true
Top voted is still 1
15
Timer running...14
true
Top voted is still 1
14
Timer running...13
true
Top voted is still 1
mapefy voted for 2
2
vote valid
13
Timer running...12
2
12
Timer running...11
true
Top voted is still 1
zachtie voted for 1
3
vote valid
11
Timer running...10
3
10
Timer running...9
9
Timer running...8
smoooore voted for 8
2
vote valid
8
Timer running...7
4
true
Top voted is still 1
7
Timer running...6
6
Timer running...5
5
Timer running...4
4
Timer running...3
true
Top voted is still 1
3
Timer running...2
2
Timer running...1
1
Timer running...0
Timer finished!
Voting has stopped!
false
20
Timer running...19
19
Timer running...18
18
Timer running...17
17
Timer running...16
16
Timer running...15
15
Timer running...14
14
Timer running...13
13
Timer running...12
12
Timer running...11
11
Timer running...10
10
Timer running...9
9
Timer running...8
8
Timer running...7
7
Timer running...6
6
Timer running...5
5
Timer running...4
4
Timer running...3
3
Timer running...2
2
Timer running...1
1
Timer running...0
Timer finished!
Voting has stopped!
20
Timer running...19
19
Timer running...18
18
Timer running...17
17
Timer running...16
16
Timer running...15
15
Timer running...14
14
Timer running...13
13
Timer running...12
12
Timer running...11
11
Timer running...10
10
Timer running...9
9
Timer running...8
8
Timer running...7
7
Timer running...6
6
Timer running...5
5
Timer running...4
4
Timer running...3
3
Timer running...2
2
Timer running...1
1
Timer running...0
Timer finished!
Voting has stopped!
20
Timer running...19
19
Timer running...18
18
Timer running...17
17
Timer running...16
16
Timer running...15
15
Timer running...14
14
Timer running...13
13
Timer running...12
12
Timer running...11
11
Timer running...10
10
Timer running...9
========PROGRAM WAS TERMINATED HERE BY AN EXCEPTION IN ANOTHER PART OF THE CODE===========

I have tried to make a isTimerActive Boolean. I wansnt able to replicate the conditions as this code can only run in the feild and I have limited helpers. This error has not happened on other similar cases despite me thinking it should break more often.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with your time function, recursion is only good if you know how to come out of it, it can create a lot of havoc in your code.

```
let timer = 20;
const timerDefault = 20;
const startTimer = () => {
    
    if (timer > 0) { //2
        console.log(timer);
        timer--;
        r.set(`Timer`, JSON.stringify(timer));
        console.log('Timer running...' + timer);
        setTimeout(startTimer, 1000); // 1
        
    } else {
        console.log('Timer finished!');
        stopVoting();
        pauseEvents();
        openCase();
        timer = timerDefault; //3
    }
};
```

1. You keep passing the function itself in the setTimeout and timer > 0 you keep passing it - in this case, it will be called 19 times.
2. On the 19th attempt, when the timer is 0 it will go to else where you are setting up the timer again to 20. When you pass `startTimer` it creates a closure that points to the timer and all the other calls to point to the same variable - timer.
3. I am not sure why you want it to be set to a default value like this.

> Why exactly is the timer running again after its done. Look at log
> file to see handle msg was not called again after voting.

it is because you are updating the timer value to default and it is in closure scope and will reset the timer for all the existing timer function to default values.

Run the below code and check the console in the browser.

```js
let timer = 20;
const timerDefault = 20;
const startTimer = () => {

    if (timer > 0) { //2
        console.log(timer);
        timer--;
        //r.set(`Timer`, JSON.stringify(timer));
        console.log('Timer running...' + timer);
        console.dir(startTimer) // here you can check the scopes array - check the script one that points to closure
        setTimeout(startTimer, 1000); // 1

    } else {
        console.log('Timer finished!')
        timer = timerDefault; //3
    }
};

startTimer();
```

> What should I do to get this proper. I'm new to coding and this is my
> biggest project. feel free to let me know im making mistakes :D

From the prompt, I am still not sure what you want to achieve. if you can update the prompt. I can try to point you in the correct direction.

Note: please check this link for [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)